# return the first row of value when a column has the same value 4 times consecutively

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Thanks for the help in advance. I'm working in MS SQL Server 2008 and trying to capture data from the first row with a value of "0" in the Auto_Manual column, where there are at least four "0"s in a row. Here is a sample of my data:

```
Lot      DateTimeStamp  Auto_Manual rn
----------------------------------------
abc123   1/4/2017 2:08      1        1
abc123   1/4/2017 2:10      1        2
abc123   1/4/2017 2:12      1        3
abc123   1/4/2017 2:14      1        4
abc123   1/4/2017 2:16      1        5
abc123   1/4/2017 2:18      1        6
abc123   1/4/2017 2:20      1        7
abc123   1/4/2017 2:22      1        8
abc123   1/4/2017 2:24      0        1
abc123   1/4/2017 2:26      1        9
abc123   1/4/2017 2:28      1        10
abc123   1/4/2017 2:30      1        11
abc123   1/4/2017 2:32      0        2
abc123   1/4/2017 2:34      1        12
abc123   1/4/2017 2:36      1        13
abc123   1/4/2017 2:38      0        3
abc123   1/4/2017 2:40      0        4
abc123   1/4/2017 2:42      0        5
abc123   1/4/2017 2:44      0        6
abc123   1/4/2017 2:46      0        7
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Lot      DateTimeStamp  Auto_Manual rn
----------------------------------------
abc123   1/4/2017 2:38      0        3
```

So far, all I've been able to do is get the row number partitioned by the Lot and Auto_Manual columns:

```
select 
   Lot
  ,DateTimeStamp
  ,Auto_Manual
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Lot, Auto_Manual 
  order by DateTimeStamp) rn

  from dbo.Table )  tmp

  order by Lot, DateTimeStamp
```

I'm able to select the row where rn = 1 for either Auto_Manual = 0 or 1, but that's not exactly what I'm looking to do. I only want the first row where there are 4 consecutive "0"s in the Auto_Manual column. Please note that an alternative could be to find the first Auto_Manual value of "0" where 8 minutes later the value is still "0". This only works if there are only "0" in between as well...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit ugly, but it should work:

```
select * from (
    select 
        *, last_value(RN) over (partition by GRP order by DateTimeStamp RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as LASTVAL, 
        row_number() over (partition by GRP order by DateTimeStamp) as RN2
    from (
    select *, RN - row_number() over (order by DateTimeStamp asc) GRP
        from (
            select
              *, row_number() over (order by DateTimeStamp asc) as RN
            from Table1
        ) X where Auto_Manual = 0
    ) Y 
) Z where LASTVAL >= RN+3 and RN2 = 1
order by DateTimeStamp
```

First this numbers all the rows, then filters just those that have 0. Those rows are numbered again and the difference between numbers is used to group them. If the difference stays the same, then they belong to consecutive group.

This group is then handled with last_value, and if the last value is current row + 3 or greater, then there's at least 4 rows, and there's one more row number for choosing the first one of that group.

For 2008 you could do something like this:

```
select min(DateTimeStamp)
from (
    select *, RN - row_number() over (order by DateTimeStamp asc) GRP
    from (
        select
          *, row_number() over (order by DateTimeStamp asc) as RN
        from Table1
    ) X where Auto_Manual = 0
) Y
group by GRP
having count(*) >= 4
```

Comment: James, thank you so much for the help. I should have specified that I am using SQL Server 2008. It loos like last_value is a function that came with 2012.. I'm sorry for not including that info in the OP. Is there a potential work around?

Comment: Ah, I only looked at the tags... You can replace the last value of course with an inner select, but that's not that good for performance. One option could to use group by for the dates, and take min and then find the rest of the data based on that

Comment: The second solution you provided for 2008 returns three values: 1/4/2017 2:24  ||  1/4/2017 2:32  ||  1/4/2017 2:38. So it looks like it is correctly grouping and selecting the min rn for each group. But unfortunately, it is selecting the min for all groups, not just the one with 4+ consecutively. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the last row, having will filter out groups with 3 or less rows

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.